# When using the kinematic formulas, if you take left direction as negative, does every single vector pointing in the left have to be negative?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, vectors

For example, a question where a boy is running to the left.

If I take left as negative, does that mean every single vector, initial velocity, final velocity, acceleration, have to be negative (unless the acceleration or velocity is in the opposite direction)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. When choosing your coordinates, you have to be consistent with them until the end of the problem. If your coordinates grow when moving to the right, they should decrease when moving to the left.

However, depending on the situation you are analysing, this may be ignored. For example, if you have a string going around a fixed pulley, the *magnitudes* of the forces on the two ends of the string may be equaled. So, in specific problems, you may get around the signals and solve using only the scalar quantities, but you should always be careful when doing this.